# How to create relational data with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, screen-scraping, relationship

Is there any builtin support in Scrapy for generating relational data? For example, when scraping a list of books I'd like to create "author", "book" and "publisher" items, the "book" item referencing "author" and "publisher".

For this I'd need a lookup mechanism to check if a related item exists. If it doesn't, I need some kind of id-generating mechanism to create the related item. Any examples?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built-in. You have to design your extracted-data model to include some unique ID for each of your entities.

Example of IDs:

- a URL (of an author's or publisher's page) or part of it
- an HTML element attribute

Example data model for books and authors:

```
class Book(Item):
    name = Field()
    uid = Field()
    url = Field()
    isbn = Field()

    author_name = Field()
    author_uid =  = Field()

    publisher_name = Field()
    publisher_uid = Field()

class Author(Item):
    name = Field()
    uid = Field()
    url = Field()
    biography = Field()
```

Then you have to post-process your output items to create those relations, and you can also crawl all the linked entities pages for more detail (populating biography from author pages)